# PHP : create variable dynamically

Tags: php, oop

I have one of my class method like this shown below :

```
public function something() {
    $this->create_varible('test');
    return $test;
}
```

I wanna create some variable(not class variable) by passing it's name as argument to `create variable method`(as shown above), then return it's value.

your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For the life of me I can't think why you'd need to do this, could you explain a little further?

Comment: That makes no sense... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't get the point in this question too... Strange...

Comment: this question sounds simple but it isn't

Comment: just wanna create a variable from a class method by passing it's name as an argument for the method and then return it's value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Example:**

```
<?php

public function create_variable($name, $value) {
  // Dynamically create the variable.
  $this->{$name} = $value;
}
```

**Or:**

```
<?php

$stack = 'overflow';
${$stack} = 'example';

echo $overflow;
```

Please keep in mind the scope of variables.

Comment: I've updated my example with an alternative which will create a variable (not a class variable) but please keep in mind the scope of variables. That dynamically created variable will only be available in that function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point in that either. But to answer your question literally:

You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) for that purpose:

```
public function something() {
    extract($this->create_varible('test'));
    return $test;
}

public function create_varible($varname) {
    return array ($varname => 12345);
}
```

The `->create_varible` by itself cannot create a variable in the invokers scope. That's why you need to wrap the call in `extract()` to get something like the desired effect; whatever its purpose.

<sup>(Yes, aware of the typo.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

How about using PHP's [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), specifically the [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [`__set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) methods.

```
class Foo
{
  public function __set($varName, $value)
  {
    $GLOBALS[$varName] = $value;
  }
  public function __get($varname)
  {
    return isset($GLOBALS[$varName]) ? $GLOBALS[$varName] : null;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->test = "Bar";
echo $test; // output: Bar
```

Demo found here: http://www.ideone.com/nluJ5

*P.S. I mention this because if your use of `$this->`, and assume you're dealing with objects.*

*P.P.S. I think @Francois has the better solution, but offering another alternative.*

Comment: thanks brad, your answer seems useful, but how to do that for just a variable(not array)

Comment: And, BTW, you can set variables within the [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) superglobal using either solution. e.g. `$GLOBALS[$varName] = $value` sticking with my example.

Comment: Didn't you say "not class variable" ?!

Comment: @Pawan: See my update. FlyBy: Indeed, I adjusted the solution for that.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes: Agreed, but you can also limit it to a direct class method call. Admittedly I didn't fully understand the question at first, and felt `__Set`/`__Get` was the solution. But a create_Var method off the class that uses `$GLOBALS` would probably be their answer.

Comment: I agree that using `$GLOBALS` sounds like the answer. It's bad practice and I'm honestly not sure that it's the ideal solution but given the limited amount of information the OP has shared (e.g. we don't know what he's trying to do), it's the best answer.

Comment: hmmm agree with you both, i realize i'm not on a right way, thanks francois and bred